# Node/Express - How to wait until For Loop is over to respond with JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function in my express app that makes multiple queries within a For Loop and I need to design a callback that responds with JSON when the loop is finished.  But, I'm not sure how to do this in Node yet.  Here is what I have so far, but it's not yet working...

```
exports.contacts_create = function(req, res) {
  var contacts = req.body;
  (function(res, contacts) {
    for (var property in contacts) { // for each contact, save to db
       if( !isNaN(property) ) {      
           contact = contacts[property];
                var newContact  = new Contact(contact);
                newContact.user = req.user.id
                newContact.save(function(err) {
                   if (err) {  console.log(err) };
                }); // .save
       }; // if !isNAN
    }; // for
            self.response();
  })(); // function
}; // contacts_create

exports.response = function(req, res, success) {
    res.json('finished');
};
```

Comment: http://howtonode.org/control-flow http://howtonode.org/control-flow-part-ii  http://howtonode.org/control-flow-part-iii  (this last one contains a snippet just like yours)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code besides just the callback structure.

```
var contacts = req.body;
(function(res, contacts) {

   ...

})(); // function
```

^ you are redefining `contacts` and `res` in the parameter list, but not passing in any arguments, so inside your function `res` and `contacts` will be `undefined`.

Also, not sure where your `self` variable is coming from, but maybe you defined that elsewhere.

As to the callback structure, you're looking for something like this (assuming contacts is an Array):

```
exports.contacts_create = function(req, res) {
  var contacts = req.body;

  var iterator = function (i) {
    if (i >= contacts.length) {
      res.json('finished'); // or call self.response() or whatever
      return;
    }

    contact = contacts[i];
    var newContact  = new Contact(contact);
    newContact.user = req.user.id
    newContact.save(function(err) {
      if (err)
        console.log(err); //if this is really a failure, you should call response here and return

      iterator(i + 1); //re-call this function with the next index
    });

  };

  iterator(0); //start the async "for" loop
};
```

However, you may want to consider performing your database saves in parallel. Something like this:

```
var savesPending = contacts.length;
var saveCallback = function (i, err) {
  if (err)
    console.log('Saving contact ' + i + ' failed.');

  if (--savesPending === 0)
    res.json('finished');
};

for (var i in contacts) {
  ...
  newContact.save(saveCallback.bind(null, i));
}
```

This way you don't have to wait for each save to complete before starting the next round-trip to the database.

If you're unfamiliar with why I used `saveCallback.bind(null, i)`, it's basically so the callback can know which contact failed in the event of an error. See [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) if you need a reference.

Comment: I'd recommend using some async flow control module to handle async for loop. [caolan/async](https://github.com/caolan/async) is the easiest one to start with.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny I try not to answer questions like this with just "use a library" since I think doing it yourself a few times helps new people understand the asynchronous concepts, and gives them the tools to do much more. However, using a library like async, and specifically `async.each()` in this case, would be a great idea in the long run.